# SQL Factorial ErlangC

Tags: t-sql, sqldatatypes, factorial, largenumber

I am trying to use this factorial in an ErlangC Function.. However my number of Agents can get up to the 300s. With this you can get pretty large numbers. For [example](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=315!). My question is how do I store and calculate these numbers? Is there a way in native SQL. I know I can go to CLR and make an outside function. But for simplicity I would like to keep this native SQL. Really trying to get to 9 and 10 from [here](http://www.mitan.co.uk/erlang/elgcmath.htm). But I will get that done when I solve this one. Thank you in advance for any assistance you can provide.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Factorial] ( @iNumber int )
    RETURNS float
    AS
    BEGIN

    Declare @i float
        IF @iNumber <= 1
            SET @i = 1    
        ELSE
            SET @i = @iNumber
            WHILE @iNumber > 1
            BEGIN

            SET @i = @i * (@iNumber - 1)
                Set @iNumber = @iNumber -1 
            END

    RETURN (@i)
    END
```

ErlangC code is as follows:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [AMS].[ErlangC]
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @m float  -- Number of Agents
    ,@u float -- Traffic floatensity
)
RETURNS float
AS
BEGIN
--Source http://www.mitan.co.uk/erlang/elgcmath.htm Number 6

    -- Return Variable
    DECLARE @Prob Float -- Probability of Call not being answered immediately and having to wait.

    -- Variables
    Declare @Numerator Float -- Top of Equation
    Declare @Denominator Float -- Bottom of Equation
    Declare @Summation float -- Summation part of Denominator
    Declare @k float    -- increment for summation


    --Calculate Numerator

    SET @Numerator = Power(@u,@m)/dbo.Factorial(@m) 

    -- Start Summation with k starting at 0.
    SET @k = 0
    SET @Summation = 0

    While @k < @m-1
    Begin
        SET @Summation = @Summation + Power(@u,@k)/dbo.Factorial(@k)
        SET @k = @k +1
    End

    --Calculate denominator

    SET @Denominator = Power(@u,@m)/dbo.Factorial(@m) + (1-@u/@m)*@Summation

    SET @Prob = @Numerator/@Denominator

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @Prob

END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found someone else's code and it works... But I am not sure why.. basically instead of doing the factorial they do the power and factorial together using a logarithm to get the same number as if you had exponentially multiplied out the numbers.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[PowerFactorial] ( @m float,  @u float)
RETURNS float
AS
BEGIN

Declare @counter float --counter
Declare @total float -- return value

SET @counter = 1
SET @total = 0

WHILE @counter <= @u
BEGIN

SET @total = @total + Log(@m/@counter)
    Set @counter= @counter + 1

END

RETURN Exp(@total)
END
```

Which would change ErlangC to this.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [AMS].[ErlangC]
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @m float  -- Number of Agents
    ,@u float -- Traffic intensity
)
RETURNS float
AS
BEGIN
--Source http://www.mitan.co.uk/erlang/elgcmath.htm Number 6

    -- Return Variable
    DECLARE @Prob Float -- Probability of Call not being answered immediately and having to wait.

    -- Variables
    Declare @Numerator Float -- Top of Equation
    Declare @Denominator Float -- Bottom of Equation
    Declare @Summation float -- Summation part of Denominator
    Declare @k float    -- increment for summation


    --Calculate Numerator

    SET @Numerator = dbo.PowerFactorial(@u,@m)  

    -- Start Summation with k starting at 0.
    SET @k = 0
    SET @Summation = 0

    While @k < @m-1
    Begin
        SET @Summation = @Summation + dbo.PowerFactorial(@u,@k)
        SET @k = @k +1
    End

    --Calculate denominator

    SET @Denominator = dbo.PowerFactorial(@u,@m) + (1-@u/@m)*@Summation

    SET @Prob = @Numerator/@Denominator

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @Prob

END
```

If anyone has any insight on how the function works please comment. Thanks..